# send base64 encoded image in inline email body

Tags: java, android, base64, html-email

I am trying to send image in inline form of email body through html embedding the data.The html is being showed right but the image is now being showed in place of image i'm seeing a small block written "obj".I have also converted bitmap img in base64 form.Here is the code:

```
public void imageRetrieved(byte[] img) 
{
        Bitmap newImg=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img,0,img.length);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    newImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.d("LOOK", imageEncoded);

    String txtBody = "<html><body><h1>hi it is stoneage product</h1><br><img src ='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageEncoded+"'/></body></html>";
    Log.d("data", txtBody);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");           
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testemail");    
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(txtBody));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

}

Help me out kindly

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me

```
    File pngDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"saved_images/"); 
    if (!pngDir.exists())
    {
        pngDir.mkdirs();
    }              
    File pngfile=new File(pngDir,"stoneage.jpg");
    Uri pngUri =Uri.fromFile(pngfile);
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{""});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi it is stoneage product Hi this is test mail with attachment");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,pngUri);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: if not work than simple to save bitmap image to sdcard and giveit that path

Comment: i did this too but i don't know why there is still "obj" is being shown in place of image

Comment: now my code is like <html><body><h1>hi it is stoneage product</h1><br><img src =file:///storage/sdcard/saved_images/stoneage.jpg/></body></html>

Comment: i appreciate for ur response @Amit but new updated code is also not working same "obj" is shown in place of image

Comment: Please you just try to attach already saved image on sdcard not to base64 converted

Comment: i did this but still same problem here is the updated code now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834933/embed-a-image-in-email-body-from-saving-and-picking-in-sdcard-in-android