# embed a image in email body from saving and picking in sdcard in android

Tags: android, image-processing, html-email, android-sdcard, email-client

I'm trying to embed a inline image in email body by saving in sdcard and then picking from that place but image is not being shown and just "obj" is shown there.Kindly help me out,here is the code of my function:

```
   {

    Bitmap newImg=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img,0,img.length);

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "stoneage.jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);

    try{
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           newImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Uri uri = null;
    uri = Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/saved_images/"+fname);


    String txtBody = "<html><body><h1>hi it is stoneage product</h1><br><img src ="+uri+"/></body></html>";
    Log.d("data", txtBody);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");

  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testemail");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(txtBody));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this to save the file:

```
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.jpg");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(txtData.getText());
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }





    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("application/image");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail}); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From My App"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/mysdfile.jpg"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

And make sure you add the correct permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

Comment: i have added permission and image is being saved in sdcard... The problem is it is not being inline embedding in email body even i added image from my drawable resources and the same problem is occuring

Comment: I have edited my code above. From your code it looks like you never added the picture as an attachment.

Comment: Image attachment is working 100% rightly but i wanted to send image in inline body of email.Anyhow thanx for ur contribution.Now i made up my mind for attaching image.